# Get tab URL in chrome extension after tab has loaded

Tags: google-chrome-extension

So there are many questions and answers on getting tab url but this is quite different.
How do I get the tab url after it has been loaded. example code below

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if(changeInfo.status == "complete"){
    // changeInfo doesn't contain url parameter anymore
    console.log(changeInfo.url); // undefined
  }
});
```

Is there any way? help, please.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the URL can be found in the tab parameter. I never checked